# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@f3ad3a0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was just trying to run my project after adding a progress bar to it(which was done successfully) but now whenever I tried to run the project it shows an error like this: `Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@17ebfcf.` I tried to clean and rebuild project, along with invalidating the caches but, the error was still there, I tried all the solutions given on this site related to my query like: changing the `'` symbol to `/'` in the `Strings.xml` file and I also followed the suggestions given by android studio (Restarting the process) but the problem wasn't resolved. Since I am a beginner, I don't exactly know what piece of code should I give related to this kind of error (hence, please advise what is need as reference).
And also I performing these activities in **Splash Screen** files not the **Main Activity**
files.

Comment: replace '  symbol to \'   instead of /' this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, apparently, this build problem was due to a version control issue.

I had added some resource files to my Android Studio project, and made alterations to others (all having to do with colors).  The IDE showed no problems with the code in any of these files, and I could see nothing suspicious.

Then I noticed one file hadn't been added to SVN.  When I tried to add it, it gave:

```
error E155016 corrupt data ... error reading code
```

To resolve that, I copied the whole directory containing the file elsewhere, then removed the whole directory from the project, then reverted the enclosing folder, did an SVN cleanup, then replaced the folder and file, added it, and committed the add.

This magically fixed the "extract source" build problem.  Beats me --- the local contents of the files were unchanged.